# Why my smart contract's function always return 0?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, private-blockchain, transaction-propagation

I'm new on Ethereum.
I'm trying to deploy my first smart contract in my private blockchain but my function always returns 0.
I wrote the simple Smart Contract:

```
pragma solidity^0.5.0;

contract helloNumber {
    int256 internal thisNumber;
    constructor() public {
        thisNumber = 4;
    }

   function showNumber() external pure returns (int256) {
        return 4;  
   }
}
```

I generated Abi and BIN with solc

```
 solcjs --bin helloNumber.sol
 solcjs --bin helloNumber.sol
```

result Bin

> 60806040523480156100115760006000fd5b505b600460006000508190909055505b610026565b6090806100346000396000f3fe608060405234801560105760006000fd5b5060043610602c5760003560e01c806376dad22314603257602c565b60006000fd5b6038604e565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b6000600490506058565b9056fea265627a7a7231582090f812ea4d2db2a047f1e42576b9cd85f3c0bef7e9392797864143a00ce269c664736f6c634300050b0032

result ABI:

> [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"showNumber","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"","type":"int256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]

in my shell conneted to my private blockchain:

```
var contract = eth.contract(ABI)
var bytecode = '0xBIN'
var deploy = {from:eth.coinbase, data:bytecode, gas: 2000000}
var object= contract .new(deploy)

object.address //returns the hashcode of smart contract on private blockchain. 

object.showNumber() **//returns always 0.**
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help and sorry if it's a silly question but I'new in Ethereum. 
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Javascript code should be asynchronous (either with `async`/`await`, or using `Promise` objects), because both `contract.new` and `object.showNumber` return a `Promise`.

For example:

```
async function run() {
    var contract = eth.contract(ABI);
    var bytecode = '0xBIN';
    var deploy = {from: eth.coinbase, data: bytecode, gas: 2000000};
    var object = await contract.new(deploy);
    var n = await object.showNumber();
    console.log(n);
}
```

Then you can either call `run()` at the end of your script, or call `await run()` from some other `async` function.